# Highcharts waterfall chart shows unknown number in one series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

We are using stacked waterfall chart of highcharts in our application. For one combination of series data we are seeing a suspicious number getting displayed in the chart, we are not passing it in series data. Below is the example (red box on top of "Dec 20" bar),

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/gn69bea1)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'waterfall',
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define the `isIntermediateSum` for this point.

```
  {
    name: 'Dec 20',
    y: 0,
    //isIntermediateSum: true
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qyhke036/